# Convert string to float. Column headers have a % sign in them

Tags: string, pandas, data-conversion

I have a data frame with nba statistics and each stat is currently an object. I was able to convert most of these to floats, however, I get an error message when trying to convert the ones which have a % in the column header e.g. FG%, 3P%, 2P%.

[image: Data]

[image: dtypes]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How exactly are you converting them?

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading this into a DataFrame. I believe you obtained your data from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/drgilermo/nba-players-stats)?

When I load this CSV into a DataFrame, all the types you listed as objects are float64 automatically. My pandas version is 0.25.1.

If you could provide a reproducible example as Paul H's comment is nudging you towards, it would help.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Seasons_Stats.csv')
df.dtypes
Out: 
Unnamed: 0      int64
Year          float64
Player         object
Pos            object
Age           float64
Tm             object
G             float64
GS            float64
MP            float64
PER           float64
TS%           float64
3PAr          float64
FTr           float64
ORB%          float64
DRB%          float64
TRB%          float64
AST%          float64
STL%          float64
BLK%          float64
TOV%          float64
USG%          float64
blanl         float64
OWS           float64
DWS           float64
WS            float64
WS/48         float64
blank2        float64
OBPM          float64
DBPM          float64
BPM           float64
VORP          float64
FG            float64
FGA           float64
FG%           float64
3P            float64
3PA           float64
3P%           float64
2P            float64
2PA           float64
2P%           float64
eFG%          float64
FT            float64
FTA           float64
FT%           float64
ORB           float64
DRB           float64
TRB           float64
AST           float64
STL           float64
BLK           float64
TOV           float64
PF            float64
PTS           float64
dtype: object
```